# How to calculate dollar value of transaction fee from Gas price details in Ethereum transaction

Tags: ethereum, etherscan

I am looking to convert gas fee info from this api [end point](https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/accounts#get-a-list-of-normal-transactions-by-address):  into dollars (calculating taxes).

The endpoint gives 'gas', 'gasPrice' and 'gasUsed' values that I'm sure would be enough, but I can't quite work it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the price in dollars using the following formula:

```
usdPrice = gasUsed * gasPrice * ethToUsd
```

You can take the first two parameters (`gasUsed` and `gasPrice`) from `etherscan`. To get the current conversion rate between ETH and USD (`ethToUsd`) you need to query some exchange API, e.g., https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/.

Comment: What is the unit of `gasUsed` is it `gwei`?